# Updating and inserting, Duplicate keys

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I've made some changes to this over the last few days and I'm still having issues and unable to produce the correct results.

The following query is for keeping a log of CSR agents by their phone extension and date.

The goal: When this runs throughout the day, it should add any info for extensions not already in the table for the day and update the metrics for the existing ones. If agents 1-5 have been on the phones all day, they're metrics should keep updating and if agent 6 gets on the phones at 3 pm, they should be inserted at that time and update for the rest of the day. However, when the next day starts I want NEW records for all agents to start over, so after 8/8/17, the records for that day should remain and never be overwritten so we can keep a history within this table.

I'm wondering if my problem is with my 'duplicate key update' arguments, but I'm new to that statement so I'm not sure. My primary key is 'Extension', but 'Extension', 'ExtID', and 'Record_date' are all Non NUll. I also put a unique index on 'Extension' and 'Record_date' to make the 'On Duplicate key update' recognize both fields, I"m just not sure it's working.

I just want to update for the current day, and start new records/new inserts on the next day. I.e., if 6 agents work every day for four days, I want the table to have 24 records at the end of the 4th day, I just want the daily records updating throughout.

Thank you for any helpful info. Here's the query:

```
    Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Date_of_report, Time_of_report )  
SELECT 
 c.extension as Extension
,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
, sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
, round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound   
, sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inboundambition_test
, sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
, count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
, date(now())
,NOW()
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
        ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
      ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
 group by c.extension
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds =values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls), 
Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), 
Date_of_report = values(Date_of_report),
Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report);
```

[image]

Comment: See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: What problem you are facing while executing the command? Make sure you have created table structure/unique key as per your requirements.

Comment: Can you show your CREATE statement? You need to have a PRIMARY KEY for the agent, date and no other UNIQUE KEY (if you have another UNIQUE KEY, you will get a duplicate)

Comment: @nacho this is my create statement:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueExtDate
ON test.ambition_test(Extension, Record_Date);

Comment: @money I ran it this morning and it had 6 records from 8/4/17 in there, but it just overwrote them for today, at least for the agents that are working today. I have created the index like so:
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniqueExtDate
ON test.ambition_test(Extension, Record_Date);

Comment: Please share some real data and table structure if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes on the query, i have modified the aliases and i think it should be ok now. Try it:

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
    Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
    Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )  
SELECT 
     c.extension 
    ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID 
    , sum(Duration) as Talk_Time_seconds
    , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Talk_Time_minutes
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Outbound   
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Inbound
    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Miss_Calls
    , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Calls
    , NOW()
    , curdate() 
FROM cdrdb.session a
LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
     ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
     ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
group by c.extension
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds =values(Talk_Time_seconds), 
    Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Talk_Time_minutes), 
    Total_Outbound = values(Outbound), 
    Total_Inbound = values(Inbound), 
    Missed_calls = values(Miss_Calls), 
    Total_Calls = values(Calls), 
    Time_of_report = values(NOW());
```

Comment: Ok it seems to be giving an error for unknown column 'Talk_time_seconds' in field list. Shouldn't that match the column name in the insert?

Comment: Removed the aliases and just used the values for the fields and it worked perfectly by inserting 3 new rows. Thank you! I'm glad to see more than 6 records in the table now

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need a column with the day, so you can have a record for each day in the table test.ambition_test of type DATE (no DATETIME). I supose you have created it and it´s called Record_Date.

Then you need to make a unique index on the table test.ambition_test on the columns (Extension, Record_Date) (It will be ok if you make it primary key. You need to make sure that you don´t have another unique key on that table. You can have more indexes, but not unique (neither primary keys).

Then you can use the insert clause. See that i have changed the now() instruction by DATE(NOW()) so you only get the day.
In the query, you use Time_of_report, that i think it should be Record_Date (it must be the same that you have in the index)

```
Insert into test.ambition_test(Extension, ExtID, Total_Talk_Time_seconds,
    Total_Talk_Time_minutes,Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound, 
    Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Time_of_report,Date_of_report  )  
SELECT 
     c.extension as Extension
    ,RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID as ExtID
    , sum(Duration) as Total_Talk_Time_seconds
    , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) as Total_Talk_Time_minutes
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) as Total_Outbound   
    , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0)) as Total_Inboundambition_test
    , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) as Missed_Calls
    , count(DISTINCT b.NOTABLECALLID) as Total_Calls
    , NOW()
    , DATE(NOW()) 
    FROM cdrdb.session a
    LEFT JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
            ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
   LEFT join cdrdb.mxuser c
          ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
   WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
   AND c.extension IN (7295,7306,7218,7247,7330,7000,7358)
    group by c.extension
ON duplicate key update Total_Talk_Time_seconds =values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds), 
    Total_Talk_Time_minutes =values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes), 
    Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound), Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound), 
    Missed_calls = values(Missed_Calls), 
    Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls), 
    Time_of_report = values(Time_of_report);
```

Comment: The Time_of_report column must be of type DATE when you create the table, so it only stores the day, not the time, don´t use the TIMESTAMP or the DATETIME

Comment: Ah, that was the issue, thank you. I've done that and have the one unique index on those two columns but I added an arbitrary column for the timestamp just for testing purposes. It's updating properly, so I'll run it again in the morning to make sure it inserts the 6 new rows. Thanks so much!

Comment: I've updated my code with the newest query like you helped me with and a screenshot of the current data. As you can see, It still updated for agent extension 7358, instead of leaving the record for 7358 from yesterday and inserting a new one for today.

Comment: @Tom N. You are still using Time_of_Report  with the time as i can see in the image you have uploaded

Comment: Yes but I've added Date_of_report with only the date(now()) function and it is DATE data type. I created the unique index between extension and Date_of_report, I only converted time of report to keep an actual time stamp  but it is not indexed any longer.

Comment: @Tom N. Then you have to change your query, i am going to change my answer then. I will add the Date_of_report column

Comment: I tried that answer and it ran successfully, but see my updated screenshot. It still just updated 2 rows instead of inserting for the new date. Also, the date reflects today's date in the time of report column, but the date of report column still says 8-8-2017

Comment: I'll re-accept this answer gladly but I'm still not inserting for new date. It overwrote my 6 records from yesterday with data from today. I added an updated screenshot. Can you see any error  by that? I have extension and date of report both selected as primary key

Comment: @Tom N. I have just seen where the mistake is but i cannot solve today. Tomorrow morning i willl retake it and give you an answer